# Circle topologically different from a line interval, torus from a rectangle (proof)

Tags: general-topology

I am new to topology, so I request a proof of this intuitively simple concept, so I can start getting a grasp of the subject.

I have heard the argument:

If we remove any point from the circle, it stays connected. But there exists a point x on an interval, for which (Interval)-x, falls into two components.

Might someone offer an explanation? What point is this? Isnt it true that we may remove any point from a line?

The same question extends to the torus. I thank you in advance.

EDIT:

We define a function that sends points on the interval to points on a cirlce. If we restrict ourself around the negborhood on the circle, where the endpoints have been glued together, the inverse is not continous. Meaning we jump from one side of the interval to the other.

[image]

Why doesn't the same argument hold for the torus? Where the inverse sends us from one side of the retangle to the other, in some neigbourhood on the torus.

Comment: Removing any of the internal points of an interval leaves two connected components. Removing an end-point leaves one connected component.

Comment: Why does it leave two connected components? Is it the same for the real line? And why isn't the same true for a cirlce? Thank you for your comment

Comment: try drawing the pictures.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking it from a different perspective... If I may ask another thing.. Isn't it true, that one may remove a point from a continous line, and not change it? Meaning it stays a line? With that said, you nicely answered the question I posed in the OP. The confusion sorounding this comment, is what sparked the OP.

Comment: if you remove a point from a line, say the $X$-axis in $\mathbb R^2$, then you get two open half-lines, not a single line.

Comment: Thank you, it makes perfect sense. I'm not used to thinking in this manner, but you've helped me. I added a picture and an edit to my question, since you've cleared up the original one.